# Image processing - TIFF images in Matlab in grayscale

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, tiff

In Matlab, when I use

```
imshow('trees.tif')
```

it displays an RGB image, but when I use these two functions

```
I=imread('trees.tif')
imshow(I)
```

it displays a gray scale image, and it's still the exact same image.

This only happens with TIFF images, because when I use it for a JPEG image like so:

```
I=imread('flower.jpg')
imshow(I)
```

it displays an RGB image, and it's the same thing as `imshow('flower.jpg')`.

Can anyone please explain why the use of `imread`/`imshow` on TIFF images displays them in gray scale?

Comment: It looks like `trees.tif`uses an indexed color map, (try `>> imageinfo('trees.tif')` and look at the field `ColorType`), so `imread` apparently returns only the indexes. I'm not sure how to get the colormap out of it so that you can convert it to RGB or whathaveyou.

Comment: you are right, so if it's an index image I should get the colormap to convert it to RGB, now I get it, do you have any book to recommend for a beginner? THANK YOU

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Load the color map too:

```
[I,cmap] = imread('trees.tif');
```

Display it with the map:

```
imshow(I,cmap)
```

Convert it to RGB:

```
Irgb = ind2rgb(I,cmap)
```

So you can display and manipulate it without the colormap:

```
imshow(Irgb)
imagesc(Irgb)
% etc.
```

---

Eye candy:

[image]
[image]
[image]